# NSUnknownKeyException facing error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, sdk

I am newbie for iOS  Please help ,When I run the code for the first time, it runs successfully in emulator along with the correct output. Now for the same code it show the following error:

> 2015-10-09 11:25:30.569 ViewController[1417:44846] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key outlinebtn.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>
> (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c840f35
>   **exceptionPreprocess + 165   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c130bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45    2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010c840b79 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>
>   0x000000010bccd7b3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] +
>   259   4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c78ae80
>   -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224  5   UIKit                               0x000000010cef2c7d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506    6
>
>   UIKit                               0x000000010cd51f98
>   -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242   7   UIKit                               0x000000010cd52588 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109   8   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010cd527f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75    9
>
>   UIKit                               0x000000010cd52c8e
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27     10  UIKit                               0x000000010cc71ca9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] +
>   58    11  UIKit                               0x000000010cc72041
>   -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247  12  UIKit                               0x000000010cc7e72c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42   13  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010cc29061 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628   14  UIKit                               0x000000010cc2bd2c
>   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350   15  UIKit                               0x000000010cc2abf2
>   -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f3e92a3
>   __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16     17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c77653c
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12  18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c76c285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341    19  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010c76ba43 __CFRunLoopRun + 851   20  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010c76b486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     21  UIKit
>   0x000000010cc2a669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413    22  UIKit
>   0x000000010cc2d420 UIApplicationMain + 1282   23  ViewController
>   0x000000010bc01e43 main + 115     24  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010edd0145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

What to do ??/ please help me. I am new for iOS

Comment: Place a break-point and identify the line of crash.... and include that in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reasonthis-class-is-not-key-valu)